# Using Sysdate in trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sysdate

Hello guys I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to triggers so I'm just looking for some advice on how to do the follow trigger.

I have created a trigger that will throw an error message if someone was to delete a record during office hours however I would like to create another trigger that uses SYSDATE will not delete records from say today and future dates.

I was thinking of maybe using >=SYSDATE but I'm not sure if that is a valid sql statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER records_delete 
BEFORE DELETE 
ON RECORDS FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24MI') NOT >= sysdat 
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20669, 'You can not delete current or future records'); 
    END IF; 
END records_delete;
```

Thanks, leprejohn

Comment: Hi sorry I'm using orcale

Comment: You can certainly use regular comparison operators with dates but it's impossible to say what's wrong with your trigger if you don't share your code or error message or describe the misbehaviour.

Comment: Here is the code:

`CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER records_delete
  BEFORE DELETE ON RECORDS
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24MI') 
  NOT >= sysdat 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20669, 'You can not delete current or future records');
  END IF;
END records_delete;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're not referencing any of the fields of the table that you're deleting from.

If your table had a column called record_date then you could rewrite this as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER records_delete 
BEFORE DELETE 
ON RECORDS FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF (:old.record_date >= SYSDATE) THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20669, 'You can not delete current or future records'); 
    END IF; 
END records_delete;
```

The syntax :old. and :new. are how you reference the columns of the current record being acted upon by the trigger, with :old. being the prefix for inspecting the values before the trigger acts on it and :new. being for values after the trigger is done.  This syntax allows you to see the values before/after the trigger updates the data, which in your case doesn't matter since you're deleting records.

If you want to disregard the hours, mins, seconds of the date fields, use this in the IF statement

```
trunc(:old.record_date) >= trunc(SYSDATE)
```

If record_date is actually stored as a string instead of a date, you would convert it to a date before comparison:

```
to_date(:old.record_date, 'DDMMYYYY') >= trunc(SYSDATE)
```

Update the format mask 'DDMMYYYY" to the format your date is actually stored in.  Check the Oracle documentation for description of to_date and date format models.

Give this a shot and see if it works.

Comment: If I was to edit the record date field as its a date that is 'DDMMYYYY' would I edit the trigger to one like this?

`CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER records_delete 

BEFORE DELETE 

ON RECORDS FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    IF (:old.record_date >= SYSDATE, 'DDMMYYY') THEN
       RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20669, 'You can not delete current or future records'); 
    END IF; 
END records_delete;







`

Comment: I updated the answer to include the condition that your date is stored as a VARCHAR2

Comment: Thanks for the help Michael, the field is date not VARCHAR2

Comment: Okay, if it's actually stored as a date, use my first method.  If this answers your question, please mark this question as answered.

Comment: Thanks Michael I have another question that I might add but I don't want to create a new question for it.

Say if I wanted a trigger that looks in the payments table for staff that have been paid '0' to include their name, which site they are at, date started, main site. 

How could I go about this?

Comment: Please create a new question and ensure to include a description of your table and syntax of the trigger you've tried to write, and what the reults should look like.

Comment: Ok I will do Michael, just before I sound like a noob I want to make sure this is the correct statement.

`IF trunc(:old.record_date) >= trunc(SYSDATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') THEN`

Comment: No.  Sysdate is already a date.  TRUNC() removes the hours, minutes and seconds.  You only need to include the format mask 'DD-MM-YYYY" if you are converting a VARCHAR2 into a date using the to_date function.  Each of my three examples above are correct syntaxually.  No need to mix and match.  It sounds like you need the 2nd one:  trunc(:old.record_date) >= trunc(SYSDATE)

Comment: Feel free to play around with selecting date values from "dual".  Such as "select to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual; and select select to_char(trunc(sysdate), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;  select to_date('01-04-2015', 'DD-MM-YYYY') from dual;